# gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap not adding trailing slashes

Tags: gatsby, sitemap

I'm using [gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap) to create the sitemap for my website, but there aren't any trailing slashes. The only option I specify is the **exclude** array, which works perfectly.

I'm using Gatsby 4.21 and have specified this in my gatsby-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: `always`,
```

In version 2 of Gatsby, I used the **gatsby-plugin-force-trailing-slashes** plugin and it worked. In version 4, I removed the plugin. I did reinstall it to test, but it no longer works.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/TryGhost/gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap/issues/223) and the proposal solution is to use [`gatsby-plugin-sitemap`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sitemap/) instead, which is an official plugin and has a drop-in support.

Using `trailingSlash: always` along with `gatsby-plugin-sitemap` should work.

Comment: Thanks so much, Ferran! I appreciate your help. I’ll use gatsby-plugin-sitemap as you suggested.